# Convert pandas column with currency values like €118.5M or €60K to integers or floats

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, currency-formatting

I have a CSV file that has a column with values like €118.5M or €60K, and I need to convert these into integers or floats and then do calculations.

```
import pandas as pd    
file = pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col ="ID")    
file[:10]    
print(file)
```

€118.5M
....
€60K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn,  a quick google search finds:

```
def convert_si_to_number(x):
    total_stars = 0
    x = x.replace('€', '') 
    if 'k' in x:
        if len(x) > 1:
            total_stars = float(x.replace('k', '')) * 1000 # convert k to a thousand
    elif 'M' in x:
        if len(x) > 1:
            total_stars = float(x.replace('M', '')) * 1000000 # convert M to a million
    elif 'B' in x:
        total_stars = float(x.replace('B', '')) * 1000000000 # convert B to a Billion
    else:
        total_stars = int(x) # Less than 1000

    return int(total_stars)
```

An easy way to apply to a df is run it on a loop

```
for i, stringo in enumerate(file):
          file[i] = convert_si_to_number(stringo)
```

Comment: where are you showing how to apply this to a dataframe?

Comment: Edited a line myself for the euro sign. Why so sassy?  To apply to a dataframe you can very simply run in on a loop.

Comment: if you plan to answer a question, answer it to completeness

Comment: This has been worked for me but now i want to apply this function into file where values has this column